# Error:Module 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android-recyclerview-v7:1.1.1' depends on one or more Android Libraries but is a jar

Tags: java, android, android-assertj

Im using assertj to do some assertions not allowed in espresso but I dont understand the problem here, I did what is said in 
[here](https://github.com/square/assertj-android).

`build.gradle`

```
dependencies {

// Android Tests
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'

// RecyclerView support
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {
    // Necessary to avoid version conflicts
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android-recyclerview-v7:1.1.1'...
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
testCompile 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android-recyclerview-v7:1.1.1@aar'
```

Answer (score 0):

@Danilo Mendes: with `androidTestCompile` it works for me. Thanks a lot man.

```
androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android-recyclerview-v7:1.1.1@aar'
```